# Why Enumerable.Cast does not utilize user-defined casts?

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

Say, we have 2 classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int a;
}

public class B
{
    public int b;

    public static implicit operator B(A x)
    {
        return new B { b = x.a };
    }
}
```

Then why

```
A a = new A { a = 0 };
B b = a; //OK

List<A> listA = new List<A> { new A { a = 0 } };
List<B> listB = listA.Cast<B>().ToList(); //throws InvalidCastException
```

The same for `explicit` operator.

P.S.: casting each element manually (separetely) works

```
List<B> listB = listA.Select<A, B>(s => s).ToList(); //OK
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name of `Enumerable.Cast` is misleading as its purpose is to unbox values. It works on `IEnumerable` (*not* on `IEnumerable<T>`) to produce an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you already have an `IEnumerable<T>` `Enumerable.Cast` is most likely not the method you want to use.

Technically, it is doing something like this:

```
foreach(object obj in value)
    yield return (T)obj;
```

If `T` is something else than the boxed value, this will lead to an `InvalidCastException`.

You can test this behaviour yourself:

```
int i = 0;
object o = i;
double d1 = (double)i; // Works.
double d2 = (double)o; // Throws InvalidCastException
```

You have two possible solutions:

1. Use `Select(x => (B)x)`
2. Create an extension method `Cast` that works on an `IEnumerable<T>` rather than an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: So, does it fail because it tries to cast `object` to `B`, while I defined a cast from `A` to `B`?

Comment: It fails, because it first would need to unbox the `object` to an `A` and than do the cast. Something like `(B)(A)o`. You could maybe define a cast operator that works on `object` instead of `A` but that wouldn't make sense as most `object` instances would not be convertable.

Comment: But it is a `List<T>` where `T` is `A`. It's not an `ArrayList` or `List<object>`. Why does this boxing/unboxing issue take place?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov: `Enumerable.Cast` is defined as `public static IEnumerable<T> Cast<T>(this IEnumerable value)`. This means the method doesn't know anything about the type inside the list. You can try it yourself: `List<A> list = ...; IEnumerable values = list; foreach(var a in values) (B)a;` This will also yield this exception because `a` is an `object`. That's exactly what is happening when you use `Enumerable.Cast`.